# Could we evaluate these two indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried much with the following two integrals, even with Mathematica and Matlab but in vain

$$\int \frac{x^{4}-3x^{3}+x^{2}+2x-2}{\sqrt{x^{2}+2x+3}}dx$$
and
$$\int \frac{x^{\frac{2}{5}}}{\sqrt[3]{1+4x^{\frac{5}{2}}}}dx$$

Any help with that is very appreciated.

Comment: Now, what version of Mathematica/Matlab are you using? These should be a cinch to solve - the first elementarily, the second with $_2F_1$'s.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Could you give me a hint for the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica 12.0 gives (up to the integration constant) the first integral as
$$\frac1{12}\left((3x^3-19x^2+40x+18)\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-162\sinh^{-1}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
and the second as
$$\frac57x^{7/5}{_2F_1}\left(\frac13,\frac{14}{25};\frac{39}{25};-4x^{5/2}\right)$$